# Group list of files by half hour interval in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, group-by

I am using python 2.7,
I have a list of files in my folders, there are thousands filesare looks like this:

```
20180828-024308.dat
20180828-024434.dat
20180828-030335.dat
20180828-032114.dat
20180828-040041.dat
..........
```

They are years,month,date,hours,minutes,and seconds

I would like to group all these files into half-hour interval, (note: the year,month, and days are not changing)

I would like to have something like this:

```
1: [20180828-024308.dat,20180828-024434.dat]
2: [20180828-030335.dat,20180828-032114.dat]
3: [20180828-040041.dat,....]
.......
```

I think a list works fine for me, or a dataframe maybe.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: can you show what you have tried

Comment: @i dont see a file between 3:30-4, so the list will be empty for that group right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From :- what I understand, 
assuming your dataframe looks like:

```
print(df)

                 files
0  20180828-024308.dat
1  20180828-024434.dat
2  20180828-030335.dat
3  20180828-032114.dat
4  20180828-040041.dat

df['file_time']= pd.to_datetime(df['files'].str.split('.dat').str[0])
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='file_time',freq='1800s')])['files'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Outputs:

```
            file_time                                       files
0 2018-08-28 02:30:00  [20180828-024308.dat, 20180828-024434.dat]
1 2018-08-28 03:00:00  [20180828-030335.dat, 20180828-032114.dat]
2 2018-08-28 03:30:00                                          []
3 2018-08-28 04:00:00                       [20180828-040041.dat]
```

*Note: Since there is no file in range 3:30-4 , hence the list is empty.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by basic programming also.
So first Load all your files using os library and then use python to get the list of files.
Heres a snippet of what i am tring to say

```
import os

folderPath = '/somepath'
filesInFolder = os.listdir(folderPath)
mapOfsimmilarFiles = {}
keyForMaps = 0
for fileNames in sorted(filesInFoldeyr):
    timePartOfFile = fileNames.split('-')[-1].split('.dat')[0]
    hr = timePartOfFile[0:2]
    min = timePartOfFile[2:4]
    sec = timePartOfFile[4:]
    if len(mapOfsimmilarFiles.keys()) == 0:
        mapOfsimmilarFiles[hr+'_'+min] = [fileNames]
    else:
        minsPresentInMaps = mapOfsimmilarFiles.keys()
        hrPresent = [int(h.split('_')[0]) for h in mapOfsimmilarFiles]
        minPresent = [(h.split('_')[1]) for h in mapOfsimmilarFiles]
        for timeUsed in minsPresentInMaps:
            hrPresent = timeUsed.split('_')[0]
            minPresent = timeUsed.split('_')[1] 
            if abs(int(hrPresent)-int(hr)) == 1:
                if abs(int(minPresent)-int(min)) <=30:
                    mapOfsimmilarFiles[timeUsed].append(fileNames)
                else:
                    #same hr but not 30mins so add to map as a new entry
                    mapOfsimmilarFiles[hr+'_'+min] = [fileNames]
                break
        mapOfsimmilarFiles[hr+'_'+min] = [fileNames]
```

I hope this should help you and guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

first convert your data in to dict then join those string accordingly.

**code:**

```
d = ['20180828-024308.dat', '20180828-024434.dat', '20180828-030335.dat', '20180828-032114.dat', '20180828-040041.dat']

output = {}

for i in d:
    key = i.split('-')[0]
    key1 = i.split('-')[1]
    # print(output)
    if key in output:

        if key1[0:2] in output[key]:

            output[key][key1[0:2]].append(key1[2:])
        else:
            output[key][key1[0:2]] = [key1[2:]]
    else:
        output[key] = {}
        output[key][key1[0:2]] = [key1[2:]]

print(output)
# print("_".join("{}_{}".format(k, v) for k, v in output.items()))
main_output = []
for i in output.keys():
    temp = []
    for j in output[i].keys():
        # [s + mystring for s in mylist]
        temp.append([i + '-' + j + s for s in output[i][j]])
    main_output.extend(temp)

print(main_output)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{'20180828': {'02': ['4308.dat', '4434.dat'], '03': ['0335.dat', '2114.dat'], '04': ['0041.dat']}}
[['20180828-024308.dat', '20180828-024434.dat'], ['20180828-030335.dat', '20180828-032114.dat'], ['20180828-040041.dat']]
```